# Как правильно вывести данные из Map Java

Tags: java, массивы, ооп, arraylist, map

Всем привет. Буду благодарен за помощь. Есть задача написать достаточно простую программу про писателей и их книги. Есть класс Book с параметром - nameBook.

```
public class Book {

     public String getNameBook() {
            return nameBook;
        }
    private String nameBook;


    public Book(String name) {
        this.nameBook = name;
    }
}
```

Есть класс Author, с фамилией автора, здесь же необходимо добавить метод, который добавляет книги автора и печатает их.

```
public class Author {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Author(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    private String name;
    private Book book;

    public void addBook(Book bookName) {
        book= bookName;
    }

    public void aboutAuthor() {
        System.out.println(name + " " + book.getNameBook());
    }
}
```

и в классе main реализовать метод aboutAuthor и вывести данные в консоль в следующем формате

Джоан Роулинг Гарри Поттер, Фантастические твари

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Author author = new Author("Джоан Роулинг");
        Book bookOne = new Book("Гарри Поттер");
        Book bookTwo = new Book("Фантастические твари");
        author.addBook(bookOne);
        author.addBook(bookTwo);
        author.aboutAuthor();
    }
}
```

Проблема, что я не могу, вывести по две книги в консоле, в текущей реализации выводится только второе название книги, как я понимаю, нужно применить hashmap или treemap в классе Author, где ключ - имя автора, а значения - ArrayList c его книгами? Поправьте, направьте, плз.

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать метод автора addBooks(Book[] books), тогда станет понятно где хранить книги.

Comment: В класс `Author` добавьте простую коллекцию (достаточно список, не обязательно мапу), и добавляйте в неё книги.  Соответственно придётся изменить метод `aboutAuthor`, чтобы выводился этот список книг.

Comment: private  List <Book> bookList. Автор будет хранить в себе ссылки на свои книги.

Comment: Вы решили проблему ? Вопрос не закрыт